# No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

My Flutter application is freezing on the splash screen and I'm getting the following error log:

```
Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
I/Choreographer(18870): Skipped 75 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
D/EGL_emulation(18870): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe8885480: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe88835a0)
I/OpenGLRenderer(18870): Davey! duration=2142ms; Flags=1, IntendedVsync=65263803118670, Vsync=65265053118620, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=65265065657900, AnimationStart=65265065738100, PerformTraversalsStart=65265065780200, DrawStart=65265126086300, SyncQueued=65265197367200, SyncStart=65265199471900, IssueDrawCommandsStart=65265199680700, SwapBuffers=65265651453000, FrameCompleted=65265947767800, DequeueBufferDuration=12659000, QueueBufferDuration=920000,
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:314:7)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): <asynchronous suspension>
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #1      getApplicationDocumentsDirectory (package:path_provider/path_provider.dart:84:22)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): <asynchronous suspension>
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #2      DbContext.initDb (package:appentrega/database.dart:34:45)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): <asynchronous suspension>
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #3      DbContext.getContext (package:appentrega/database.dart:27:21)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): <asynchronous suspension>
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #4      _SplashScreenState.startTime (package:appentrega/splash.dart:16:34)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): <asynchronous suspension>
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #5      _SplashScreenState.initState (package:appentrega/splash.dart:33:5)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #6      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4068:58)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #7      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3919:5)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #8      Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3101:14)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #9      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2904:12)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #10     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5127:14)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #11     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3101:14)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #12     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2904:12)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #13     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3961:16)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #14     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3738:5)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #15     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3924:5)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #16     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3919:5)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #17     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3101:14)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #18     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2904:12)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #19     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5127:14)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #20     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3101:14)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #21     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2904:12)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #22     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5127:14)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #23     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3101:14)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #24     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2904:12)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #25     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5127:14)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #26     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3101:14)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #27     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2904:12)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #28     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5127:14)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #29     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3101:14)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #30     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2904:12)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #31     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3961:16)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #32     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3738:5)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #33     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3924:5)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #34     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4088:11)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #35     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3919:5)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #36     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3101:14)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #37     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2904:12)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #38     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3961:16)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #39     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3738:5)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #40     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3924:5)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #41     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3919:5)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #42     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3101:14)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #43     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2904:12)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
E/flutter (18870): #44
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
D/EGL_emulation(18870): eglMakeCurrent: 0xe8885720: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe88832f0)
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
 4.034ms (!)
```

Looks like the problem is here:
  [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)

Already done this:

-Deleted all plugins and reinstalled with `flutter pub get`.
-Runned `flutter clean` and `flutter run`

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This error generally occur when you get a plugin and not build the app again. If this is  your case after getting the plugin on pubspec.yaml reinstall your apk. If this is not your problem did you created your project with suport for kotlin and swift? I don't know if this is the case but most of the plugins need this

Comment: I really don't know what hapenned, I solve it by pulling the previous code from git and replace the code that I've updated. Probly messed up some deep android files or something like that, no clues.

Comment: I'm getting the same error trying to build my project with Flutter Desktop Windows. Tried a fresh git repo pull and flutter clean but still no joy. Runs fine on emulators, just getting the error on Windows.

Comment: what this answer means that the plugin contain platform code `java or kotlin` on `android` and `obj-c or swift` and these don't get pull from cache with `hot reload` or `hot restart` you need to do a full `rebuild` of your app with `flutter run` or `flutter build` depending on your development or deployment

Comment: I am getting the same error after deploying my app on the Web server. Before deploying I issued "flutter clean" and "flutter build web" commands.  My app works correctly on the Android phone.

Answer (score 38):

**Flutter for Web**

I ran into this after starting to add web support to an application. The getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() function only supports iOS and Android [(docs)](https://pub.dev/documentation/path_provider/latest/path_provider/getApplicationDocumentsDirectory.html). I added a check for web and changed the way I set the directory which fixed the "No implementation found for method" for me.

To tell if the platform is web use Flutter's kIsWeb:

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;
```

Then handle setting the directory accordingly:

```
if (kIsWeb) {
    // Set web-specific directory
} else {
    appDocumentDirectory = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
}
```

Comment: thank you, this error seems to now reappear with the more likely scenario of simply using flutter web while it's in beta and very new

Comment: What path should I use for the web-specific directory?

Comment: @Meggy Did you find any solution?

Comment: import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

if (!kIsWeb) {  //path only for android and ios
    final appDocumentDirectory = await path_provider.getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    Hive.init(appDocumentDirectory.path);
  }

Comment: i use the database example and it uses getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() at _initDatabase() its needs to be changed. I'll move to Floors : https://levelup.gitconnected.com/room-database-equivalent-for-flutter-807c9729b58d

Answer (score 36):

I got this error for a different plugin after I build the release apk,
this was because code shrinking is enabled by default - if you don't want to minify/obfuscate code just add the two lines inside  android/app/build.gradle.

```
android {
    ...

    buildTypes {
        release {
            ...
         
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me. I had a problem with the PathProvider missing implementations. After adding the above 2 lines and generate an app-bundle, it solved the problem. Please note this problem didn't happen on the emulators for Android and iOS. It only happened after creating an app-bundle.

Answer (score 7):

If your package depends on [flutter_facebook_auth](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_facebook_auth), you need to make sure you have performed the setup for [Android](https://facebook.meedu.app/#/android) and iOS to get rid of the error. I was using Hive and Facebook login and surprisingly, the missing Facebook setup was causing Hive.initFlutter() to throw this error.

This fix will work even if you don't actually have the Facebook app setup on your Facebook Developers account.

Comment: Thanks mate ! 
I couldn't figure out what had happened all of a sudden.
Thanks to your answer that I could relate and think of the solution.

Comment: Thanks bro, the problem was the facebook plugin I really have no idea whats wrong with flutter and facebook plugins

Comment: Thanks Mate. Its necessary that you configure facebook auth both for iOS and Android.

Answer (score 6):

Turned out I had to quit the flutter run process and start it up again. Just a full restart within flutter run didn't work.

Here is a link for reference https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10912

Edit: Be sure you import these packages;

1. package:path_provider/path_provider.dart
2. dart:io
3. dart:async

Comment: This saved me a lot of time. Whenever in doubt of a package not working, just quitting the run process and starting it up again might do the trick.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to reinstall app

OR

You can manage permissions using https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler runtime

generally when you mention permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file it asks for permission when app starts for first time that's why you need to reinstall app or give permissions from permission manager or you can handle it from your app dynamically using above package

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is register the corresponding plugin method channel in the `Application.java`(or `Application.kt`). So it's this:

```dart
package com.example.lifely;

import io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.PluginRegistry.PluginRegistrantCallback;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;
import io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin;

public class Application extends FlutterApplication implements PluginRegistrantCallback {
  @Override
  public void registerWith(PluginRegistry registry) {
    PathProviderPlugin.registerWith(registry.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.pathprovider.PathProviderPlugin"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As the Flutter team working on [Dart plugin registration doesn't run in background isolates #98591](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/98591) for adopting in-package platform channels in more 1P plugins, which requires Dart plugin registration, the plugins do not work in `Isolates` out of the box, The work is still in the progress after the completion you'll need to initialize `DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized()` as `WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()` before.

Until then there is a workaround for it. [#99155](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/99155#issuecomment-1052023743)

The workaround described there will work for `path_provider` as well:

Add dependencies on `path_provider_android` and `path_provider_ios`.
At the beginning of your background isolate entry point, add something like:

```dart
if (Platform.isAndroid) PathProviderAndroid.registerWith();
if (Platform.isIOS) PathProviderIOS.registerWith();
```

Comment: Man, I'm waiting for your answer for yeeeeears. thanks.

Comment: What's a background isolate entry point?  (I didn't know I had one... IF I had one, but I have the same error as above.)

Comment: Background tasks automatically runs on another thread rather than main thread of the app. The concept of using different thread is called isolate.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I haven't included dart:async package. Running "flutter run" and including "dart:async" package resolved the problem

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the snippet below was missing from my AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
```

Adding it in the AndroidManifest.xml file fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Had this error while using **cached_network_image** on a **Flutter MacOS desktop app** - think it was caused by the 2.0.0 update of path_provider package:

[image: Screenshot of path_provider changelogs for 2.0.0]

I think because the path_provider function that cached_network_image uses (`getTemporaryDirectory()`) doesn't have paths defined on desktop, this causes it to throw the error.

[image: Screenshot from path_provider package docs]

To solve this (in my case), I imported the path_provider_macos package (https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider_macos) and registered it in main before my app started up.

```dart
void main() {
  PathProviderMacOS.registerWith();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

I haven't tested other platforms but packages exist for linux (https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider_linux) and windows (https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider_windows) so should hopefully fix the issue on these platforms as well.

Comment: There is no `PathProviderMacOS.registerWith();` in my `path_provider_macos` package OR my `path_provider` package (which is supposed to include the path_provider_macos package). It seems that either your answer is outdated, or you're missing some crucial class definition or similar that you have made but forgot to tell us about...  It would be great if you could provide an update! 

Comment: Just had a look at the [github repo](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/main/packages/path_provider/path_provider_macos/lib/path_provider_macos.dart) for the path_provider_macos package and the method seems to be there even in the latest package version (2.0.6). It's a static method so are you sure you aren't instantiating the PathProviderMacOS class? Do you have an error message at all?

Comment: Just the normal: "Undefined name 'PathProviderMacOS'. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.". My app is not for MacOS, though! It's for Android, but I just thought I'd try it... Could that be why? ‍♀️

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if I'm able to help you apart from suggesting that you check that you've installed the package correctly following the steps [here](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider_macos/install), but I'm certain the method exists there just seems to be an issue with how you are importing the package. Maybe try deleting pubspec.lock and running the `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` commands as well to refresh the pub cache.

Comment: Very weird, indeed... Anyway, my problem was solved as you can see in my answer, so... perhaps we best leave this, for now.  Thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was for the cache, I have removed cached_network_image and replaced it with Image.network and the problem has disappeared

Answer (score 0):

With these codes, I got same error with web. It works for Windows.

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
...
  final document = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(document.path);
```

Replacing it with Hive.initFlutter() looks cover it all (Windows, web, and Android):

```
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
...
  await Hive.initFlutter();
```

PS: I haven't tried on iOS, but should work too.

Comment: getApplicationDocumentsDirectory() throws error in IOS ```Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)```.

for Ios we need to add code 
if (Platform.isIOS) {
        getApplicationSupportDirectory().then((Directory directory) {
          Hive.init(directory.path);
        });

Answer (score 0):

I had this error ("MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)") in an old app that I had to run with `flutter run --ignore-deprecation`, because it was using an old Android embedding and I didn't want to migrate it just now.

But it worked out, because I removed this line from my `app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file:

```
android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
```

and magically, the error disappeared!

Hope it helps someone else, as well.

Answer (score 0):

1. ```
   import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

     Future<Directory?>? _externalDocumentsDirectory;

     void _requestAppDocumentsDirectory() {
       setState(() {
         _externalDocumentsDirectory = getExternalStorageDirectory();
       });
     }

     Widget _buildDirectory(
           BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Directory?> snapshot) {
         Text text = const Text('');
         if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
           if (snapshot.hasError) {
             text = Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
           } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
             text = Text('path: ${snapshot.data!.path} ');

             print(snapshot.data!.path); //
             createExcel(snapshot.data!.path); // I send a string with the route
           } else {
             text = const Text('path unavailable');
           }
         }
         return Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0), child: text);
       }
   ```
2. 

```
ElevatedButton(
               style: ButtonStyle(
               backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                 const Color.fromARGB(255, 39, 136, 42),
                ),
               ),
               onPressed: _requestAppDocumentsDirectory,
               child: const Text(
                 'Exportar contraseñas',
                ),
               ),
             FutureBuilder<Directory?>(
               future: _externalDocumentsDirectory,
               builder: _buildDirectory,
             ),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIfwC.png)

More information in the library documentation: https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider/example

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that worked for me was to delete the cache at `%USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dev\path_provider-2.1.2`

To be thorough, I also did

```
flutter clean
flutter pub remove path_provider
flutter pub add path_provider
flutter run -d windows
```

And it finally works!

Answer (score -1):

**After Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects !!**

if you don't have a lot of time trying editing AppDelegate.h of step 5

I pass after updating by following the guide: [Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects) apply the following actions:

1. Update flutter to its latest stable version -> flutter clean is missing
2. Update all your dependencies (it is very likely that packages have or ask you to add new methods) -> flutter clean is not too much
3. Update the code and methods resulting from the package update
4. Try flutter run or from android Studio |> (some packages may send you missingPluginException but if it is installed on the mobile) go to step 5.
5. Build the test installs for android and IOS if you can (they should work fine).
   It is likely that in development with flutter run it continues to send the error, in my case I cannot test in IOS but with flutter run it runs for both android and IOS and the problem is solved by adding it to ios / Runner / AppDelegate.h ->[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry: self];

   #import <Flutter / Flutter.h>
   #import <UIKit / UIKit.h>

   @interface AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate
   [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry: self];
   @EnD

If after these steps it cannot be executed in step 4 0 5, verify that other dependencies have not updated their versions to be compatible with Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects !. For example cached_network_image uses path_provider try uninstalling the cached_network_image package
Repeat from step 4 again.

Comment: you can clearly see it's an android issue not iOS