# No implementation found for method app_settings on channel app_settings

Tags: flutter, dart

Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method app_settings on channel app_settings)
#0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:7)

Answer (score 2):

Consider to **uninstall and reinstall your app.** It solved my issue.

> This error generally occur when you get a plugin and not build the app
> again. If this is your case after getting the plugin on pubspec.yaml
> reinstall your apk. If this is not your problem did you created your
> project with suport for kotlin and swift? I don't know if this is the
> case but most of the plugins need this

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58082118/12695188