# Flutter package "just_audio" throws exception

Tags: flutter, just-audio

The exception is [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getTemporaryDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider).
I implement this package to my sample project and it worked. But when I tried to implement to my official project it throwed above exception. How can I fix it? Thanks a lot

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63787347/10659482

Comment: it doesn't work with me

Answer (score 3):

See: "[The Dreaded MissingPluginException](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/62006)"

This particular error unfortunately gives poor diagnostic information. It can be caused by adding a plugin to your project in debug mode without restarting the app, it can also be caused when using a plugin that creates a second FlutterEngine and plugin loading within that engine fails because one of the plugins in your dependencies has a bug (and in this case it is almost certainly not the plugin that the actual error identifies), or, as most likely in your case, it can be caused in release builds if you use something like Proguard but you did not add rules to keep whatever symbols it is trying to load (you can confirm this by disabling ProGuard and seeing if it works).

There may still be other as yet unknown causes for this error. It's all a bit messy, but for now, follow the above GitHub issue to see the various causes and solutions different people have discovered for this error.

It may also help to read the [MissingPluginException FAQ](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/wiki/FAQ#why-does-my-app-get-a-missingpluginexception) I created for audio_service which may help to track down potential causes for the error.

Comment: I really appreciate it! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Using hot reload or hot restart won't work when you have included a new plugin into. your project.

Do a `flutter clean` and after that `flutter run`

Comment: Yes, I tried to do it many times but it still doesn't work

Comment: try uninstalling the app, then re-building

Comment: I also tried it bro. But nothing happened

Comment: Try to restart the machine! No, no, I'm just kidding :)

Comment: any advices? :(

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days, I just realised that the exception did not come from just_audio package. It comes from flutter_facebook_login && flutter_facebook_auth packages, maybe because my app didn't register with FB, so that is the reason. Thanks for all supports.

Comment: In that case, it sounds like the second reason. flutter_facebook_login has actually not been updated in more than a year, and therefore does not use the latest v2 plugin architecture. Plugins that haven't been updated to use v2 will break when loaded within a second FlutterEngine, and the solution is usually to find an alternative plugin or ask the developer to fix the plugin (which is difficult if the plugin is no longer being maintained). I will update my answer to link to an FAQ I created to solve this type of problem.